# Remove file permissions, creation date from rsync listing command in python?

Tags: python

I am using rsync --list-only command with Django/Python:

```
subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '--list-only', source],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           env={'RSYNC_PASSWORD': password}).communicate()[0]
```

It returned result like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx 4096 2012/11/07 09:56:23 upload
```

I don't want all the files information. I only want file name displayed like this:

```
upload
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsync has no option to abbreviate the output, you need to use a regex (or `split()`)

```
import re
retval = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '--list-only', source],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           env={'RSYNC_PASSWORD': password}).communicate()[0]
retval = re.sub('^.+?\d+:\d+:\d+\s+(\S+.+)', '\g<1>', retval)
```

Alternatively (as long as file names have no spaces)...

```
retval = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '--list-only', source],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           env={'RSYNC_PASSWORD': password}).communicate()[0]
retval = retval.split(' ')[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with the `maxsplit` argument to discard the first 4 fields. E.g.

```
>>> "drwxrwxrwx 4096 2012/11/07 09:56:23 upload".split(None, 4)[-1]
'upload'
>>> "drwxrwxrwx 4096 2012/11/07 09:56:23 doc with spaces.txt".split(None, 4)[-1]
'doc with spaces.txt'
```

`None` is used as the separator to mean *any whitespace*.

In your case, assuming your rsync command may return more than one file, you could try:

```
# retrieve output
out = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '--list-only', source],
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       env={'RSYNC_PASSWORD': password}).communicate()[0]
# parse block of text into list of strings
lines = (x.strip() for x in out.split('\n'))
# take only filenames (ignoring empty lines)
filenames = [x.split(None, 4)[-1] for x in lines if x]
```